# Slim 4 Auth Middleware redirect fails

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to use Middleware to redirect unauthenticated users into Google API auth.
If I go directly to the auth system (by going to the /auth route), the Google bit works and the user is sent to my home page. But, if I go to a Middleware protected page, I get a blank page.
Here is my Middleware:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
declare(strict_types=1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
namespace App\Middleware;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 
use Slim\Psr7\Response;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface as RequestHandler;                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
class Auth                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response                                                                                                                                                                          
   {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        $response = new Response();                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        $response->withHeader('Location', '/auth')->withStatus(302);                                                                                                                                                                                   
      } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        $response = $handler->handle($request);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      return $response;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

Since the Google bit works, the issue has to be in my middleware, right? That also means that the else part of the middleware is working.
Any suggestions?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I just had not had enough coffee when I wrote this code.
I failed to set the mutated response to a variable.
Inside my if statement SHOULD be:

```
        $response = new Response();                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        $response = $response->withHeader('Location', '/auth')->withStatus(302);
```

the "**$response =**" on the second line is the part I missed. 
Hope this helps someone else.